# Combining models so a user action takes them to the next object's view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Rails app that is a collection of books that users can vote up, down or neutral -- and the vote action (which affects an attribute called 'score') should take them to the next book on its own permalink. Right now I have a model that mimics Next/Previous posts so it presents the books in order.

I'm getting an error when I try to put the models together (the one that increases the score, and the one that moves to the next book). The code below only refers to the up vote as that is the one I am trying to fix first.

view:

```
<td class="decrease"><%= link_to "meh", decrease_book_path(@book) %></td>
<td class="neutral"><%= link_to("yes.", book.next_book) if book.next_book %></td>
<td class="increase"><%= link_to "ooh!", increase_book_path(@book) %></td>
```

book model:

```
def next_book
  self.class.first(:conditions => ["id < ?", id], :order => "id desc")
end

def increase_score
    self.score ||= 0
    self.score += 1 
    self.save!
end
```

book controller:

```
def increase
    book = Book.find(params[:id])
    if book.increase_score
      next_book
    end
end
```

I don't know Ruby that well and am a Rails beginner, so greatly appreciate it if you can point me in the right direction, thanks!

Comment: In your `next_book` method, shouldn't the condition be `id > ?`, since you want to find the "next" book (which I assume means next subsequent row in the books table). Also, what is the error you're getting?

Comment: I'm starting with Book.last then going backwards so users will see new books first (might change it to random order later anyway). Error is: NoMethodError in BooksController#increase

undefined method `next_book' for #<BooksController:0x007fb429f99068>

Comment: Ok, I see. So, you're trying to call the `next_book` method as though it were a method of the `BooksController`, however it belongs to the `Book` class. So you need to do `book.next_book`. Also, as cenyongh implies, you'll need to either invoke a render or redirect action, depending on how the whole thing is supposed to behave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def increase
  book = Book.find(params[:id])
  if book.increase_score
    redirect_to next_book_path(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Comment: awesome - ended up being: `redirect_to book.next_book` thanks to @teeg's comment above